# How to create Test record in _Complaint Data view for Outlook?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views

I have a use case where I need to create a test record in the Complaint data view to test the extract. I have created an automation that extracts data from the complaint data view, due to our company's process QA needs to certify the automation is working fine. In order to test I'm trying to create a record in the complaint data view by sending an email to Outlook and marking it as junk, but no luck in creating a record. I can only send it to our company Outlook mail for compliance reasons and in our Dev environment.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks,

Comment: Not fully sure, but I think that whether a spam complaint is registered by SFMC depends on the ISP/ESP, not on the email client used - or maybe it’s a combination of both - I’d check that with SF support